# Toggle different formats for maven-assembly-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Is there a way to pass a parameter to your maven build to set which assembly format all declarations of the maven assembly plugin will use? We have a project with multiple maven modules which each contain their own assembly declaration, and we want to be able to choose dir-only, tar.gz or zip for all of these modules. The only way right now that I can think to do this is by declaring multiple profiles in each module each with their own maven-assembly-plugin section, duplicating a lot of the maven pom in each module. Is there some better way to handle this with inherited profiles or a global assembly format setting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First why do you need so different assembly formats? What is the purpose? Why not generating them all ? Please described more in detail...

Comment: The main assembly when built is large - 1.5GB. Most of the time we want to build just the dir. When we make a release, we want the zip. Some other deployment processes might expect a tar.gz.

Comment: Wow... 1.5 GiB is extremely large... What kind of things do you package? Also it would be helpful to more detailed information ...

Comment: Sure, this is for the Apache NiFi project and there are many bundled dependencies. You can see a PR going on here:
https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/5694/files